# Is postgresl SERIAL guaranteeing no gaps within single insert statement?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

Let's start with:

```
CREATE TABLE "houses" (
  "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  "name" character varying NOT NULL)
```

Imagine I try to concurrently (!) insert into the table in a single statement multiple records (maybe 10 maybe 1000).

```
INSERT INTO houses (name) VALUES
    ('B6717'),
    ('HG120');
```

Is it guaranteed that when a single thread inserts X records in a single statement (when in the same time other threads simultaneously try to insert other records to the same table) that those records will have IDs numbered from A to A+X-1 ? Or is it possible A+100 will be taken by thread 1 and A+99 by thread 2?

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever in which order they are allocated. Additionally: the client will cache sequence numbers. So even if transaction 1 allocates #1 number it's possible another transaction gets #50. Why do you care? The only thing that such a number has to provide is uniqueness. Everything else is meaningless

Comment: I care because having this property being true could possibly make implementing appending only log (inserted in particular way) synchronized to another application easier. But I learned I cannot make this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting 10000 records at once using two PgAdmin connections seems to be enough to prove that serial type does not guarantee continuity within a batch on my PostgreSQL 9.5

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..200 LOOP
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO houses (name) VALUES %s%s;', repeat('(''a' || i || '''),', 9999), '(''a' || i || ''')');  
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Above results in quite frequent overlap between ids belonging to two different batches

```
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE id BETWEEN 34370435 AND 34370535 ORDER BY id;

34370435;"b29"
34370436;"b29"
34370437;"b29"
34370438;"a100"
34370439;"b29"
34370440;"b29"
34370441;"a100"
...
```

Comment: That's not what I asked about specifically.

Comment: You are right and I edited the answer. Thanks, I learned something new today.

Comment: You inserted in 200 rows in 200 separate INSERT statements. My question specifically asked about inserting rows in a single INSERT statement.

Comment: `format()`/`repeat()` generates an `INSERT` statement with 10,000 rows that is passed to `EXECUTE`. 200 is the counter for the outer loop. Run on two connections while changing the `a` prefix manually to `b` and you get a table with 4,000,000 rows and 400 batches. Unless `EXECUTE` does some magic with the SQL that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I get it now, I had to scroll to right to understand it properly. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was going to be harder to prove but it turns out it is not guaranteed.

I used a ruby script to have 4 threads insert thousands of records simultaneously and checked whether records created by a single statement had gaps in them and they did.

```
  Thread.new do
    100.times do |u|
      House.import(1000.times.map do |i|
        {
          tenant: "#{t}-#{u}",
          name: i,
        }
      end)
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)

House.distinct.pluck(:tenant).all? do |t|
  recs = House.where(
    tenant: t,
  ).order('id').to_a
  recs.first.id - recs.first.name.to_i == recs.last.id - recs.last.name.to_i
end
```

Example of the gaps:

```
[#<House:0x00007fd2341b5e00
  id: 177002,
  tenant: "0-43",
  name: "0",>,
 #<House:0x00007fd2341b5c48
  id: 177007,
  tenant: "0-43",
  name: "1">,
  ...
```

As you can see the GAP was 5 between first and second rows inserted within the same single INSERT statement.